# Extracting all field names of a featureclass using query filter programmatically

Tags: arcobjects, .net, vb

I want to get all field names present in a feature class using queryfilter programmatically.

Comment: What methods have you tried, how far did you get, and where specifically do you need help?

Comment: Thanks whuber.....i used query filter to get selected field names.....pQueryFilter.SubFields = "city_population,city_id"....but i want all the field names without passing them within quotes( " ")....any help !

Comment: Presumably this is for ArcGIS, right?  (It's a good idea to put these details in the question itself.)

Comment: Yes,featureclasses are stored in a pgdb....

Comment: If you want all fields, just specify "*" as the IQueryFilter.SubFields property. Otherwise, you can access the list of fields through IFeatureClass.Fields.

Comment: Thanks Petr Krebs....But when i use "*" , it returns nothing....my code is :  Pqueryfilter.subfields = "*" , When i start debugging the code, I can see only one field with name as *....

Answer (score 5):

ESRI has excellent documentation for everything. With a quick search you would most probably get what you want. Below snippet is slightly modified version copied from [there](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002t9000000)

```
Public Sub DisplayDistinctFieldAliasNames(ByVal featureClass As IFeatureClass)
        Dim fields As IFields = featureClass.Fields
        Dim field As IField = Nothing

    For i As Integer = 0 To fields.FieldCount - 1
        field = fields.Field(i)
        Console.WriteLine(field.Name)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "ESRI has excellent documentation for everything" -- not sure if serious.

Comment: @blah238 - at least for the desktop SDK, its god :-)